# SQL variables in SPRING JPA

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa

I try to create my own query, but JPA don't support SET @ in context. How i can do this?

```
SET @a:=0;
UPDATE news_mod SET id=@a:=@a+1 WHERE canonical>0;
ALTER TABLE news_mod AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Comment: Or may be somebody know how to start query from MySQL Queries in Spring JPA.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.